# HTML5 and jQuery stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

Got jQuery running a HTML5 audio element. When I use:

```
audioPlayer.pause();
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
```

on a local file, it will stop the file and when you hit play again, it will restart it. However, with a Live stream, such as SHOUTcast, it will simply pause the audio, not stop it completely. How would I go about doing this?

http://www.julake.co.uk/media/loader.php?page=contact

Comment: Where does the jquery come in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
audioPlayer.pause();
audioPlayer.src = '';
audioPlayer.load();
```

Then when you click play, set `src` to the source.

```
audioPlayer.src = /* actual source */;
audioPlayer.load();
audioPlayer.play();
```

Comment: @futureslay - what happens when you do this?

Comment: When I hit pause, everything stops as it should, but nothing happens when play is clicked again.
@Daniel A. White

Comment: when you click play, set the `src` property again.

Comment: Works.
Many thanks.
Can I point you here too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590472/jquery-animate-with-slider

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
audioPlayer.pause();
audioPlayer.src = '';
audioPlayer.load();
```

After you click play set the `src` to the source of the audio:

```
audioPlayer.src = /* the proper source */;
audioPlayer.load();
audioPlayer.play();
```